# Disable Special Characters From Being Entered into @Html.TextboxFor in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, html

I have this code:

```
  <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Log.InventoryNo, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Log.InventoryNo, new {maxlength = "10", title = "e.g. PC3044241; PRN3044241; LT3044241", autocomplete = "off"})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Log.InventoryNo)
            </div>
        </div>
```

I would like it so that only numbers and alphabet letters can be entered into the textbox. It should not allow any other character in the textbox and ignore the user if they try to. I guess this would be client side validation? Is there a way to do this using JavaScript or HTML 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a fixed format you'd like to enforce, you can try the [jQuery input mask](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) plugin.

It's important that you **also** validate the data server side. Javascript can be disabled, and forms submitted manually, that will bypass any client side validation.

Given the examples in your title property:

```
jQuery(function($){
   $("#input-id").mask("aa9999999");
});
```

You can see a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/35HnP/1/)